# videojs Caption ON/OFF on toggle

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am trying to reach that **([videojs captions toggle](https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/videojs-captions-toggle))** with videojs. I couldn't use that code because is outdated and I'm using the newest version of videojs.

I tried to trigger an click on "disable subtitles" to make that toggle effect but didn't work.. Any ideias?

**EDIT:**
To clarify my question a little more what I want to achieve is:

No need to click on "disable subtitles" OR "english".
ON CLICK "CC" I would like to toggle the subtitle ON/OFF

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyGuH.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.